# Restrict access to domain classes gorm methods in grails with Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm, acl

Is there a way to define access to GORM methods (e.g.: save, delete, update) with Spring Security?

I've seen ACL's plugin documentation but, although I think that the plug-in allow me to define the access, I can't see clearly how to do this.

ACL's doc: http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-acl/docs/manual/guide/single.pdf

Note: The examples in the documentation define access on class instances individually. I want to define them in a class level.

Comment: what about defining access at a controller level in regards to save, delete or update?

Comment: That's the way I've implemented it, but I think that defining domain class level restrictions in an access control list would be a better aproach with regard to clarity and maintainability.

Comment: Problem is that ACL, as you mentioned is row level, not class level  :( I think you are already on the right track.  You could take a look at the answer below. Personally I try to keep my security simple ...

Comment: Thank for the clarification! I thinn I will continue to define access at controller level

Answer (score 1):

not sure how to do eaxactly with grails but you should write pointcut for security on domain object

```
 <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
     <!-- Block anything ending with the word 'Controller'-->
     <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* my.pkg.*Domain.*(..))" access="NON_EXISTANT_ROLE"/>
 </global-method-security>
```